# Adding information to foursquare venue page?

Tags: foursquare

My primary question is: Can connected apps add relevant information to venue pages?

I am a coder and avid Foursquare user. The basic information about venues is cool (location, photos, tips, etc.), but while I have my meal (in the case of a restaurant) I'd like to have more to read about the venue, such as the back-story, i.e., what's the history of the place, when was it founded, by who, and other interesting facts about the venue.

I thought connected apps would be the answer and that perhaps I could write a simple wiki to integrate with the venue page for users to provide their knowledge about the venue. But it seems from what I've read that's not the the intent of a connected app or the API. Am I correct is this assumption? And if so, can this idea be dropped into the Foursquare suggestion box? I think it would make a great value added feature - especially for us nerds who like to read.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great use case for connected apps. Connected apps can reply to check-ins with up to 200 characters of text, and a link to more content. This can be used to provide additional information about the venue. Take a look at https://foursquare.com/apps/ to see examples of connected apps, and the kinds of responses they give to check-ins.